# Positional Encoding and Fourier transforms

Tags: machine-learning, transformers

While I was studying Positional Encoding, I came across an article that links coding resolution to Fourier transforms:
"For anyone who has studied finite
Fourier transforms, this problem should be familiar. Only half of the frequencies are unique. "
However, even if I have explored this topic, I do not find the connection with the Fourier transform, in particular the reference to the fact that only half of the frequencies must be unique.
Can anyone help me?

Reference:
[https://towardsdatascience.com/master-positional-encoding-part-i-63c05d90a0c3#:~:text=Fourier%20transforms%2C%20this%20problem%20should%20be%20familiar.%20Only%20half%20of%20the%20frequencies%20are%20unique](https://towardsdatascience.com/master-positional-encoding-part-i-63c05d90a0c3#:%7E:text=Fourier%20transforms%2C%20this%20problem%20should%20be%20familiar.%20Only%20half%20of%20the%20frequencies%20are%20unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the statement "Only half of the frequencies are unique" refers to the [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) and the time series being real for a discrete Fourier transform. The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is defined as
$$
X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right).
$$
You can see that $X_{k + N} = X_k$. As
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_{k+N} &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i2\pi\frac{(k+N)n}{N}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i2\pi \frac{kn}{N} - i2\pi \frac{N}{N}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i2\pi \frac{kn}{N} - i2\pi\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i2\pi \frac{kn}{N}\right)\exp\left(- i2\pi\right)\\
&=  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i2\pi \frac{kn}{N}\right)\\
&= X_k
\end{aligned}
$$
This "feature" is called aliasing. Because of that only for $k \in [-N / 2, N/2 - 1]$ (assuming $N$ is even), $X_k$ are unique. And if the series to be transformed $x_n$ is real ($x_n^* = x_n$), then
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_{-k} &=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{N}(-k)n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[x^*_n\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right)\right]^*\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[x_n\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{N}kn\right)\right]^*\\
&=X^*_k,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $^*$ refers to complex conjugate. Resulting in only half of the frequencies' $X_k$ being unique.

Comment: How can i see that $ X_ {k + N} = X_k $?

Comment: As adding $N$ is the same as shifting the phase by $2\pi$, the value does not change ($\exp(i2\pi) = 1$), in details: $X_{k+N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp(-i2\pi(k+N)n/N) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp(-i2\pi kn/N - i2\pi N/N) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp(-i2\pi kn/N - i2\pi) =  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\exp(-i2\pi kn/N) = X_k$. Let me also add this to the answer.

Comment: your answer is really perfect, 
$$ exp \ left (- i2 \ pi \ right) \\ $$ is it 1 for Euler's identity (practically it is the square)?

Comment: There are a few different ways to look at it, the easiest way would be $\exp(i2\pi) = \cos(2\pi) - i\sin(2\pi) = 1$. Or if you understood $\exp(i\theta)$ as a rotational on the complex plane, rotate by $2\pi$ obviously give you $1$.

Glad that my answer helps; please consider accepting my answer.